# What is the easiest way to go with for simple drawing and event capturing in C?

Tags: c, opengl, gtk, drawing, sdl

I need to create a simple drawing program in c for graphs, i.e. nodes and lines, thus I would also need to capture events. I would need to run this in Linux and Windows ( though not a requisite for Windows for now). I haven't done any drawing in c before (a little opengl a long time ago), I am guessing my options would be gtk, sdl or opengl. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use GTK+. For graphs, cairo will be enough (it's the library used by GTK for drawing). But if you need nodes, lines and events (like moving stuff you have drawn), you'll need to use a canvas, like GooCanvas. You may also use GTK and Clutter.

Answer (score 2):

With those requirements, I'd go with GTK+. You will use Cairo for the primitive graphics, which is nice and easy.

And the events will be standard GUI events, so also easy.

GTK+ can have some learning curve, though... but certainly not more that OpenGL.